# meson: How to get a target 's name in meson

Tags: meson-build

I add a shared_library target in meson.build

```
libmali = shared_library(                                                                                  
    'mali',                                                                                                  
    dummy_source,                                                                                            
    install : true,                                                                                          
    version : meson.project_version()
)
```

I want to get the libmali's name "mali" by code elsewhere in this meson.build.
how to get?
is there any api like libmali.getname() ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but only since Meson 0.45; `shared_library()` returns a [`build target`](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#build-target-object) object, which has a method `name()` since the aforementioned version.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It is great!
However, the reference manual says that it is since 0.54, not 0.45.

Comment: To be clear, that returns the name that was passed in `meson.build` file to a target, but Meson later post-processes that name making e.g. `foo` a `libfoo.so`. Is there a way to get that post-processed target name?

Comment: @Hi-Angel: you can use the `full_path()` method to get the full path, and then use either the built-in methods of the `str` object, or using `fs.name()`